# ClojureScript multipart post through cljs-http?

Tags: http, clojure, multipart, clojurescript

I'm trying to post some files to my server through clojurescript. According to https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http, all I need to do is changing `form-params` to `multipart-params`, but once I do that  my params are getting ignored.

```
(print data-array)
(go (let [{data :body} (<! (http/post "/submit.json"
                                        {:multipart-params {:foo "bar"}}))]))
```

The print gives

```
{:image0 #<[object File]>, :image1 #<[object File]>}
```

(My goal is it to post this array of files to my url. I changed it to :foo "bar" for debug purpose). If I change `:multipart-params` to `:form-params`, my params are in the request. If I change it to `:multipart-params`, they are getting ignored.

I'm confused in why this is happening. Does someone have a hint where to go from here?

Answer (score 2):

I am still not sure what exactly the problem was, but after upgrading all libraries to the latest stable it seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I've been experimenting with file uploads from within a clojurescript app using both cljs-ajax and goog.net.IframeIo. The code is available on github at https://github.com/theophilusx/file-upload.git